# three.js multiple images on cylinder face

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am trying to display multiple images on the outside (not the top or bottom) of a rotating cylinder using three.js.  I am able to display 1 image, but my goal is to display  several side by side.  I have added 3 textures to my materials array, but only the first is displayed.  Any help is appreciated.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>My first three.js app</title>
    <span>Test</span>
    <style>
        body { margin: 0; }
        canvas { width: 100%; height: 100% }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="js/three.js"></script>
    <script>
        var scene = new THREE.Scene();
        var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 100, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );
        camera.position.y = 24;

        var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
        renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
        document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

        var diameter = 20;
        var geometry = new THREE.CylinderGeometry( diameter, diameter, 15, 32 );

        var texture1 = new THREE.TextureLoader().load( 'images/image1.jpg' );
        var texture2 = new THREE.TextureLoader().load( 'images/image2.jpg' );
        var texture3 = new THREE.TextureLoader().load( 'images/image3.png' );

        texture1.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
        //texture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
        //texture.repeat.set( 1, 4 );

        var materials = [];
        materials.push(new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ map: texture1 }));
        materials.push(new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ map: texture2 }));
        materials.push(new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ map: texture3 }));

        var cylinder = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, materials );
        cylinder.position.y = 25;
        scene.add( cylinder);

        camera.position.z = 40;


        function render() {
            requestAnimationFrame(render);
            //cylinder.rotation.z += 0.05;
          cylinder.rotation.y += 0.005;
            renderer.render(scene, camera);
        }
        render();
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way is to assign textures to each face of your geometry using `geometry.faces[i].materialIndex` property. In this case you should use the number of radial segments that is a multiple of three (if you have 3 textures).

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/89/three.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My first three.js app</title>
    <style>
        body { margin: 0; overflow:hidden;}
        canvas { width: 100%; height: 100% }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<script>
    var scene = new THREE.Scene();
    var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 100, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );
    camera.position.y = 24;

    var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

    var diameter = 20;
    var radialSegments = 33;
    var geometry = new THREE.CylinderGeometry( diameter, diameter, 15, radialSegments );
    
    var img1 = "http://d2gg9evh47fn9z.cloudfront.net/800px_COLOURBOX9108127.jpg";
    var img2 = "http://d2gg9evh47fn9z.cloudfront.net/thumb_COLOURBOX8923432.jpg";
    var img3 = "http://d2gg9evh47fn9z.cloudfront.net/800px_COLOURBOX19377428.jpg";

    var texture1 = new THREE.TextureLoader().load( img1 );
    var texture2 = new THREE.TextureLoader().load( img2 );
    var texture3 = new THREE.TextureLoader().load( img3 );

    THREE.DefaultLoadingManager.onLoad = function () {
        var materials = [];
        materials.push(new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ map: texture1 }));
        materials.push(new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ map: texture2 }));
        materials.push(new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ map: texture3 }));
        var l = geometry.faces.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
            if (geometry.faces[i].normal.y !== 0) {
                // these are caps
                geometry.faces[i].materialIndex = 0;
            } else {
                // each segment has 2 faces
                geometry.faces[i].materialIndex = Math.floor(i * 3 / (radialSegments * 2));
            }
        }

        var cylinder = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, materials);
        cylinder.position.y = 25;
        scene.add( cylinder);

        camera.position.z = 40;

        function render() {
            requestAnimationFrame(render);
            cylinder.rotation.y += 0.005;
            renderer.render(scene, camera);
        }
        render();
    }
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to apply three textures to your cylinder.

If you don't want to merge your textures into a single texture, one easy solution is to render three cylinder wedges, each with its own texture. Use a pattern like the following:

```
var group = new THREE.Group();
scene.add( group );

var geometry = new THREE.CylinderBufferGeometry( 5, 5, 10, 16, 1, false, 0, 2 * Math.PI / 3 ); // 1/3 cylinder wedge

var endCapMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial();

// mesh
mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, [ new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: texture1 } ), endCapMaterial, endCapMaterial ] );
mesh.rotation.set( 0, 0, 0 );
group.add( mesh );

mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, [ new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: texture2 } ), endCapMaterial, endCapMaterial ] );
mesh.rotation.set( 0, 2 * Math.PI / 3, 0 );
group.add( mesh );

mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, [ new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: texture3 } ), endCapMaterial, endCapMaterial ] );
mesh.rotation.set( 0, 4 * Math.PI / 3, 0 );
group.add( mesh );
```

three.js r.89